# Linear programming with "nice" matrices

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming

Consider the following linear programming problem
\begin{array}{ll} 
\text{minimize} & \mathrm 1^{\top} \mathrm x\\ 
\text{subject to} & v\le \mathrm A \mathrm x \le u\\ 
& \mathrm x \geq 0
\end{array}
Suppose $A$ is a 'very nice' matrix: highly structured, positive-definite, we know all eigenvalues/eigenvectors. Are there any special methods, approaches, or tricks which could help us accelerate numerical solution and/or analysis of the problem.

Comment: Tell us the structure.

Comment: The matrix A is a close relative of a graph Laplacian, where the underlying graph is a lattice.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it helps much unless we know more about the structure of $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ beyond symmetric positive definiteness. The LP as given can be rewritten as
$$\begin{array}{ll} 
\underset{y\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize}} & \mathrm c^{\top} y\\ 
\text{subject to} & v \preceq \mathrm y \preceq u,\\ 
& A^{-1}y \succeq 0,
\end{array}$$
with $y:=Ax$ and $c:=A^{-1}\rm{1}$. Following standard calculations, the Lagrange dual LP is
$$\begin{array}{ll} 
\underset{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^{3n}}{\text{minimize}} & d^{\top} \lambda\\ 
\text{subject to} & M\lambda = c,\\ 
& \lambda \succeq 0,
\end{array}$$
where $d:=\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
-v\\
0_{n\times 1}
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{3n}$, $M:=[-I_n \: I_n \: A^{-1}]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 3n}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!